# Reading only doubles from a file of strings, char, and doubles

Tags: c++, text-files

This is a sample of the file I have (this is one line):

```
B12                          MN =                              1.2                         G_{I}=                          3.4                               G_{B}  =                           9.4                        J_k =                               4.4                  1.4                      0.4                   -0.1                       -0.1               3.3                 9.3                      -5.7                 2
```

Now, my trouble is that I need to be a able to read this file and get the numbers I'm interested in into another file.

So, I tried this:

```
ifstream in("Data.dat")
ofstream out
output.open("Output.dat")

double a1, ..., a12; 

while(1) {
           if(!(in >> a1 >> ... >> a12))
           break;

           output << a1 << a2 << a12; //say these are the three doubles I'm interested in.


}
```

However, this failed. I don't get anything in the output file. I really have no clue how to fix this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `if(!(in >> a1 >> ... >> a12));` does nothing at all. Are you sure there is supposed to be a `;` at the end?

Comment: You could read them all as strings and convert/keep track of the valid ones with [`stod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) or [`strtod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof).

Comment: @Aesthete I corrected this to what I tried exactly. Which I guess is also wrong.

Comment: @chris I see, if these are all in the same line. If I use getline it will consider all of this as one string. So how can I read each one separately as a string?

Comment: @stupidity, You can just have one string for the current output, `in >> str`, check if it's a double, and `output << str` if it is.

Comment: Regular expressions, `std::regex` is a good place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use 'string' instead of 'double', and the test codes are as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ifstream in("t1.txt");
    string a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9;
    ofstream out("t2.txt");

    while(1)
    {
        if((in>>a1>>a2>>a3>>a4>>a5>>a6>>a7>>a8>>a9))
        {
            out<<a1<<a3<<a5<<endl;
        }
        else
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```